# How to get application status in spark standalone cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

As per the official spark documentation we can check the status using
`spark-submit --master spark://IP-ADDRESS:PORT --status SUBMISSION_ID`

However when I tried using the same it was not able to establish a connection.
The master URL and the PORT is valid and my spark is running in standalone cluster with default config.

```
spark-submit --master spark://10.xx.xx8.xx5:7077 --status driver-20191119160551-0003
19/11/19 17:45:10 WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://10.xx.xx8.xx5:7077.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestConnectionException: Unable to connect to server
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$requestSubmissionStatus$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$requestSubmissionStatus$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:148)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.requestSubmissionStatus(RestSubmissionClient.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.requestStatus(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestConnectionException: No response from server
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.readResponse(RestSubmissionClient.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.org$apache$spark$deploy$rest$RestSubmissionClient$$get(RestSubmissionClient.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$requestSubmissionStatus$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:152)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.readResponse(RestSubmissionClient.scala:278)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the standalone server?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski no trace of logs for that command

Comment: How did you deploy your Spark app? Can you access the web UI of the spark standalone cluster (the master's)? Can you show the logs where the IP is printed out to make sure what you use and what's used by the master match?

Comment: @Gokulraj , to rule out any network/firewall issues - have you tried to ssh IP-ADDRESS and execute `spark-submit --status` locally?